# How to use asyncio, aiohttp web scraper with fastapi?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio, fastapi, aiohttp

I am learning web scraping using asyncio and aiohttp with beautifulsoup. I want to create a RESTful API to get user input, scrape the data and then show the response in json format. This is how my scraper code looks like;

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

class TestScraper:
    def __init__(self, query):
        self.query = query

    async def main(self):
        urls = [
            f"https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{self.query}.html",
            f"https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{self.query}/",
        ]

        def get_urls(session):
            tasks = []
            for url in urls:
                tasks.append(session.get(url))
            return tasks

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = get_urls(session)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            for r in responses:
                if (str(r.url).split(".")[0][8:]) == "books":
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(
                        await r.read(), "lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer("article")
                    )
                    books_list = []
                    for books in soup.find_all("article"):
                        book_name = books.find("h3").find("a").get("title")
                        book_price = books.find("p", class_="price_color").text
                        books_item = {
                            "book_name": book_name,
                            "book_price": book_price,
                        }
                        books_list.append(books_item)
                    yield books_list

                elif (str(r.url).split(".")[0][8:]) == "quotes":
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(
                        await r.read(),
                        "lxml",
                        parse_only=SoupStrainer("div", {"class": "quote"}),
                    )
                    quotes_list = []
                    for quotes in soup.find_all("div", class_="quote"):
                        quote_text = quotes.find("span", class_="text").get_text()
                        quote_author = quotes.find("small", class_="author").get_text()
                        quotes_item = {
                            "quote_text": quote_text,
                            "quote_author": quote_author,
                        }
                        quotes_list.append(quotes_item)
                    yield quotes_list

                else:
                    yield "No results found"

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(TestScraper(6).main())
# asyncio.run(TestScraper({query}).main())
```

It's working fine but when I try to use it with FastAPI it returns errors. Even after doing some changes which I found from the web the errors still appear. Here is my FastAPI code;

```
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI

from scrapers.books_quotes import TestScraper

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.get("/test/{test_query}")
async def read_test_items(test_query: str):
    return asyncio.run(TestScraper(test_query).main())
```

And the error I get;

> asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

`asyncio.run` is meant as the top-level entry point for the async code, which the FastAPI app (or some other framework which you use to run it) should already call for you.

Normally, to run an `async def` function (= [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine)) from within async code, simply `await` it.

```
@app.get("/test/{test_query}")
async def read_test_items(test_query: str):
    return await TestScraper(test_query).main()
```

In your case, `TestScraper.main` is not a normal coroutine but an [asynchronous generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-generator) (because it uses `yield` statements). You run it by using it in an `async for` loop.

```
@app.get("/test/{test_query}")
async def read_test_items(test_query: str):
    async for result in TestScraper(test_query).main():
        # do something with result
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list for each URL in TestScraper code, created a single list for all URLs.

```
#same code as before
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = get_urls(session)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            results = []
            for r in responses:
                if (str(r.url).split(".")[0][8:]) == "books":
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(
                        await r.read(), "lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer("article")
                    )
                    for books in soup.find_all("article"):
                        book_name = books.find("h3").find("a").get("title")
                        book_price = books.find("p", class_="price_color").text
                        books_item = {
                            "book_name": book_name,
                            "book_price": book_price,
                        }
                        results.append(books_item)
                elif (str(r.url).split(".")[0][8:]) == "quotes":
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(
                        await r.read(),
                        "lxml",
                        parse_only=SoupStrainer("div", {"class": "quote"}),
                    )
                    for quotes in soup.find_all("div", class_="quote"):
                        quote_text = quotes.find("span", class_="text").get_text()
                        quote_author = quotes.find("small", class_="author").get_text()
                        quotes_item = {
                            "quote_text": quote_text,
                            "quote_author": quote_author,
                        }
                        results.append(quotes_item)
                else:
                    results.append({"error": f"No results found for {r.url}"})
            yield results
            #print(results)
#same code as before
```

And thanks to [@mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) changed the FastAPI file i.e. main.py code as shown below;

```
#same code as before
@app.get("/test/{test_query}")
async def read_test_items(test_query: str):
    async for results in TestScraper(test_query).main():
        return results
```

And now everything works fine. Thanks for reading and have a nice day.